# CocoaPods: Can't install FBSDK 5.6.0

Tags: ios, cocoapods, fbsdk

I'm trying to update my FBSDK pods from version **5.0.0** to **5.6.0** through these lines in my *Podfile*:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.6.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.6.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.6.0'
```

I ran `pod repo update` successfully, but `pod install` and `pod update` always give me this:

```
Specs satisfying the `FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.6.0), FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

(Sometimes it's the same error, but for FBSDKShareKit.)

My deployment target is everywhere set to **9.0** (in *Podfile* and *project.pbxproj*) and according to the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/5.6.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json), FBSDKCoreKit requires **8.0** (if I read it correctly). I also tried increasing it up to **13.2**, but it didn't help.

What am I missing?